# Compute human readable timestamp from floating point (EasyIP)?

Tags: xml, firebird

I need to convert some date+timestamps in XML data extracted from Easy-IP.  I don't recognize the raw values, they appear to be a floating point value, but the whole number portion is too small for UNIX style.

I will probably encounter extracted data from this type of system again, so I'd like to have a standard way of converting it that doesn't rely upon having direct access to the database (which could be different or inaccessible)

I believe the back-end database is Firebird, but according to their documentation, they start counting up from Jan 1st, 1753.

Some sample values (each line is a different entity), which should all refer to activities that occurred in the last 15 years, and probably much more recent:

```
CREATED="39660.2632087847" UPDATED="39660.2632160185"
CREATED="39660.2631284838" UPDATED="39750.4032429514"
FIRST_SUCCESSFUL_CONTACT="39668.128960544"  LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CONTACT="41301.0505147685"
FIRST_SUCCESSFUL_CONTACT="39668.1289603588" LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CONTACT="41301.0505142245"
```

My hope is that someone else has already seen this before, and not to pose a puzzle.  Bonus points if you have a reliable way to convert to a date+timestamp using XSL, Java, or (less preferred) PERL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the values come from the internal Delphi [TDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.TDateTime) representation:

Delphi programs internally represents TDateTime values as a floating point value, the integral part represents the number of days since Dec-30-1899 and the fractional part is the fraction of the day since midnight.

So, for example,

- `39660` is `Jul-31-2008`
- `0.2632087847` is `6:19:01.239 AM`

Thus, your first example is `2008-07-31 06:19:01`

I don't think the data is a Internal Firebird representation of dates, so my guess is also the original system don't used the `TimeStamp` data type, but a Double precision or other numeric type to store the dates.

With all this said, it looks like the simplest way to convert the dates is to write a program in Delphi to change the date representation. For example, to calculate the shown dates, I wrote:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dt: TDateTime;
begin
  Dt := 39660.2632087847;
  ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', Dt));
end;
```

If you don't have Delphi at hand, there are [other tools](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html) which use similar representations, and you have now all the info to do the Math by yourself if you're out of luck.  A conversion to UnixTime is not particularly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an accurate example of this conversion for Java.  Here's a simplified version of what I'll be using:

```
public static String convertEasyIPTime (double dateTimeDouble, String timeZoneCode) {

  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneCode);

  long days = (long) dateTimeDouble;
  long adjustedDays = days - 25569; // Days between Jan 1st 1753 (Delphi) and Dec 31st 1970 (Java)

  long datePortion = adjustedDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  long timePortion =  (long) ((dateTimeDouble - days) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);

  int zoneAndDSTOffset = tz.getOffset(datePortion);

  Date output = new Date (datePortion + timePortion - zoneAndDSTOffset);
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");  
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneCode)); 
  return formatter.format(output);
}
```

A sample of calling it:

```
System.out.println(convertEasyIPTime (39940.1295844213d, "CST"));
```